# How to allow an app to take screenshots automatically?

Tags: privacy, automation, screenshots, automate

How can I allow an app to automatically take screenshot?

I'm not talking about apps disabling screenshots on them, I can take screenshot of the thing manually, but I'd like to automate it. I use the app Automate, which has a screenshot action, but when I run it, a dialog appears asking me if I want to allow the app to see everything what is on screen, and that happens every time. I basically want to autoapprove this dialog.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: MacroDroid can do it, but requires root access. Autoinput app (root not needed) also has this feature but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: I think Auto Input takes advantage of the ADB over Network feature... It initiates an ADB Connection via the Local Host 127.0.0.1 ... This Feature has been removed for security concerns...

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I got one possible workaround: use the Automate interact touch block to click on the confirmation button, like in this flow:

[image: flow]